# Javascript help, get input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have this code.

```
  <form name="validar">
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"></p>
    <p><input type="password" placeholder="clave"></p>
    <p class="mensaje">¿Cuanto es <strong></strong>?</p>
    <p><input type="number" name="captcha" placeholder="resultado de la cuenta"></p>
    <button type="submit">Ir</button>
  </form>
```

and i want to get the "captcha" value the user enter.
I try this but it wont work. Any help?

```
var campo = document.getElementsByName('captcha');
var valor = campo.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByName` returns a collection. You need to access an individual element

```
var campo = document.getElementsByName('captcha')[0];
var valor = campo.value;
```

Comment: thanks, and i i want to do it by. Document.querySelector(). Is document.querySelector("captcha") ok?

Comment: You could do it like `document.querySelector("[name='captcha']")`

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
<form name="validar" onsubmit="validate()">
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"></p>
    <p><input type="password" placeholder="clave"></p>
    <p class="mensaje">¿Cuanto es <strong></strong>?</p>
    <p><input type="number" name="captcha" placeholder="resultado de la cuenta"></p>
    <button type="submit">Ir</button>
</form>
```

And it..

```
function validate(){
    var form = document.forms['validar'];
    var campo = form['captcha'];
    alert(campo.value);
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and what is your solution?